# Wait itself within endless loop, but user can cancel every time

Tags: swift, loops, user-interface, delay, delayed-job

In Swift 3 I have a loop which can be canceled by user pressing a button. Within the loop some checks are made. After the check, the task can sleep for a minute. But when calling the task with

```
let delayQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myApp.queue3", qos: .utility)
let additionalTime: DispatchTimeInterval = .seconds(3)

repeat {
    delayQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + additionalTime) { self.update() }
} while !self.stop
```

the loop itself needs to run all the time waiting for the user
"stop", indicates, that user clicked on stop button.
Is that waste of CPU power? How could I avoid this loop to be done all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Timer instead.

```
var timer: Timer?
let timeInterval: TimeInterval = 3

func didPressCancelButton() {
    timer?.invalidate()
}

func beginUpdates() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
        timeInterval: timeInterval,
        target: self, 
        selector: #selector(self.update),
        userInfo: nil, 
        repeats: true
    );
}

func update() {
    print("Updated")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks as easy as I like it.

Comment: One question: In the solution above the timer is calling a task on the main DispatchQueue? Because I don't get updates on dialog items which runs in main queue I need to start it as a different queue, e.g. Utility.

Comment: `func update() {
        print(Thread.current)
        print("Updated")
 }`
Output: <NSThread: 0x600000068c00>{number = 1, name = main}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of delaying execution in thread with an outer loop you can put your loop in thread instead and make it to sleep.

```
import Foundation

class YourUpdatingClass {

    private let updateQueue: OperationQueue
    init() {
        updateQueue = OperationQueue()
        updateQueue.name = "com.myApp.queue3"
        updateQueue.qualityOfService = .utility
    }

    private var updateOperation: BlockOperation?

    @IBAction func startUpdating() {
        guard updateOperation == nil else {
            // In case if updating already started
            return
        }

        updateOperation = BlockOperation { [weak self] in
            while true {
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
                self?.update()
            }
        }

        updateQueue.addOperation(updateOperation!) // we just created updateOperation, so we can use `!`, but use it with caution
    }

    @IBAction func stopUpdating() {
        updateOperation?.cancel()
        updateOperation = nil
    }

    private func update() {
        print("update") // Whatever your update does
    }

}
```

You updating is contained in eternal while loop which takes a nap every 3 seconds.

Stopping is managed by cancelling operation, instead of checking some var in the loop.

Comment: Great. I will use this solution, if it gets more complicated. It is the more general solution. Thanks a lot!